# Parsing SNS with Nodejs via Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I'm trying to parse an SNS message triggered by CloudFormation, and then pass variables to a function that gets details about the stack, and sends them to an other SNS topic

When creating a Cloudformation stack, several SNS messages are sent. I've successfully got the exports.handler piece of my code parsing for the "Create_Complete" notification for the stack. From there, it parses the rest of the message and creates a couple variables which I'm trying to pass to my list_stack_resources function, which I'd like to use to get details about the resources created by the stack, and then send those details to another SNS topic which I'll subscribe to.

Here is a sample SNS notification

```
StackId='arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:999999999999:stack/SNS-TEST/9999999-999-9999-9999-99999999999'
Timestamp='2019-01-15T21:27:09.503Z'
EventId='50aba940-190c-11e9-982b-0af0c7a25b8e'
LogicalResourceId='SNS-TEST'
Namespace='652493332725'
PhysicalResourceId='arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:999999999999:stack/SNS-TEST/9999999-999-9999-9999-99999999999'
PrincipalId='652493332725'
ResourceProperties='null'
ResourceStatus='CREATE_COMPLETE'
ResourceStatusReason=''
ResourceType='AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'
StackName='SNS-TEST'
ClientRequestToken='Console-CreateStack-9999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999'
```

Here is my node js code:

```
    topic_arn = "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:652493332725:AB-Lambda-To-SNS";
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 
    AWS.config.region_array = topic_arn.split(':'); // splits the ARN in to and array 
    AWS.config.region = AWS.config.region_array[3];  // makes the 4th variable in the array (will always be the region)

    // ####################   BEGIN LOGGING   ########################
    console.log(topic_arn);   // just for logging to the that the var was parsed correctly
    console.log(AWS.config.region_array); // to see if the SPLIT command worked
    console.log(AWS.config.region_array[3]); // to see if it got the region correctly
    console.log(AWS.config.region); // to confirm that it set the AWS.config.region to the correct region from the ARN
    // ####################  END LOGGING (you can remove this logging section)  ########################

    // Searches SNS messages for stack creation complete notification, parses values to create variables for StackId and LogicalResourceId
    exports.handler = function(event, context) {
        const message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
        if ((message.indexOf("ResourceStatus='CREATE_COMPLETE'") > -1) && (message.indexOf("ResourceType='AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'") > -1)) {
            var fields = message.split("\n");
            subject = fields[11].replace(/['']+/g, '');
            stack_id = fields[11].replace(/['']+|StackName=/g, '');        
            logical_resource_id = fields[3].replace(/['']+|LogicalResourceId=/g, '');        
            list_stack_resources(stack_id);
        }
    };

    // describes resources created by the stack and publishes results to the send_SNS_notification function
    function list_stack_resources(stack_id) {
        var cloudformation = new AWS.CloudFormation();
        cloudformation.listStackResources({
                StackName: stack_id,
        },  function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else     resources = data;           // successful response
            send_SNS_notification(resources);        
            });
        }

function send_SNS_notification(resources) {
    var sns = new AWS.SNS();
    sns.publish({ 
        Subject: "subject",
        Message: resources,
        TopicArn: topic_arn
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
            return;
        } 
        console.log('push sent');
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

I don't believe variables in the list_stack_resources function are working properly.

Comment: What error do you get? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I assume you're using Node 8 as your runtime since you don't have a callback in your handler function signature.*

Looking at your code, it looks like it does not take into account that Javascript is asynchronous so handler finishes without wanting for `list_stack_resources()` to finish.

**My solution (using Node 8 and async/await):**

1. Your function should return a Promise.

```
    exports.handler = function (event, context) {
        const message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
        if ((message.indexOf("ResourceStatus='CREATE_COMPLETE'") > -1) && (message.indexOf("ResourceType='AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'") > -1)) {
            var fields = message.split("\n");
            subject = fields[11].replace(/['']+/g, '');
            stack_id = fields[11].replace(/['']+|StackName=/g, '');
            logical_resource_id = fields[3].replace(/['']+|LogicalResourceId=/g, '');

            return list_stack_resources(stack_id);
        }

        // Up to you to decide the return value but all code branches should return.
        return true;
    };
```

2. Use async/await.

```
    async function list_stack_resources(stack_id) {
        const cloudformation = new AWS.CloudFormation();

        try {
            const resources = await cloudformation.listStackResources({
                StackName: stack_id,
            }).promise();

            return send_SNS_notification(resources);
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        }
    }

    async function send_SNS_notification(resources) {
        const sns = new AWS.SNS();

        try {
            const data = await sns.publish({
                Subject: "subject",
                Message: resources,
                TopicArn: topic_arn
            }).promise();

            console.log('push sent');
            console.log(data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
        }
    }
```